# Can I use Aspose.Cells dll free with microsoft visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, aspose-cells

I was wondering if I can use Aspose.Cells.dll. I downloaded it from the their website.

https://downloads.aspose.com/cells

I'm curious do I just need to add the dll to my project? Can they charge me or my workplace? Is the Dll file that I downloaded just code? Does a free version exsist? Does the DLL connect to the internet? What is a DLL? I'm really confused.

I didn't put in any information just download and created an account on their website? Could I be going against the licensing agreement by adding the dll to Microsoft Visual Studio.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

No, Aspose.Cells is not free. You will have to use a license file to make it work fully. But if you will not set a license, it will still work, but it will print **Evaluation Warnings** on your output excel, pdf, html and image files etc. If these warnings do not bother you, then you can use it freely. But if you don't want these warnings, then you should purchase a license. Please contact [Aspose.Purchase](https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.purchase/220/showforum.aspx) team for your purchase related queries if you have any.

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose